# Google Maps markerClusterer: how can I pass options at init when adding lib via unpkg?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, parameter-passing, markerclusterer, unpkg

I'm currently trying to implement [Google Maps JavaScript MarkerClusterer](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-markerclusterer) on a Magento 2 website.

As Magento 2 front-end workflow goes, I can't use ES6+ import/export feature (unless I'm in developer mode). There's no use of NPM in Magento 2.

MarkerClusterer documentation states that when adding via unpkg (which is what I do), the MarkerClusterer can be accessed at `markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer` ([last line of the "Install" section here](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-markerclusterer#install)).

I'm fine when declaring my cluster object the following way (clusters are showing on map with default algorithm and renderer): `let cluster = new markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer({ markers, map });`.

However, I'm struggling with overriding default parameters (I need to add a `clusterClass` and custom icons).

At first (before I realised I won't be able to use ES6+ import/export feature), It worked like a charm when declaring my cluster object the following way:

```js
let cluster = new MarkerClusterer(
    map,
    markers, {
        clusterClass: "marker-cluster__icon",
        imagePath: mapOperator.imageBasePath + "pin-cluster-",
    });
```

I have no clue about how to pass new options/parameters with the following syntax which I have no choice about using: `let cluster = new markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer({ markers, map });`.

I couldn't find any example over the internet as everyone is using NPM or any kind of other modern front-end workflows nowadays.

The following, as an example, is not working:

```js
let config = {
    markers: {
        clusterClass: "marker-cluster__icon",
        imagePath: mapOperator.imageBasePath + "pin-cluster-",
    },
    map
}

let cluster = new markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer(config);
```

For me, that's still an obscure part of how javascript is working. Hope someone can lighten my path...

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue, preferably a working [StackSnippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to specify custom cluster marker for a Google map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71129102/how-to-specify-custom-cluster-marker-for-a-google-map)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to apply custom icons for clustering in google maps markerclusterer because unable to provide position data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70020054/unable-to-apply-custom-icons-for-clustering-in-google-maps-markerclusterer-becau)

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to @geocodezip, I was finally able to reach my goal. Following thread's answer (which is not exactly a duplicate) helped breaking the deadlock: [Unable to apply custom icons for clustering in google maps markerclusterer because unable to provide position data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71428553/19637661).

One remaining caveat is that I wasn't able to add a custom CSS class to the label (to the marker cluster icon HTML element), which would have helped to get a more secured focus on it (than `.map [title][aria-label][role="button"]`) for styling the information of the amount of markers in a cluster.

I've tried several solutions including [google.maps.MarkerLabel interface className property](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#MarkerLabel.className), [clusterClass option as mentioned here](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-markerclustererplus/interfaces/MarkerClustererOptions.html#clusterClass) and [cssClass option as mentioned here](https://github.com/gmaps-marker-clusterer/gmaps-marker-clusterer/tree/feature/css-class-option#custom-css), but none of them seemed to be working...

```js
let renderer = {
    render: ({ count, position }) =>
        new google.maps.Marker({
            label: {
                text: String(count),
                color: "transparent",
            },
            position,
            icon: {
                url: mapOperator.imageBasePath + "pin-cluster.png",
            },
            zIndex: Number(google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX) + count,
        }),
};

let config = { map, markers, renderer };
let cluster = new markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer(config);
```

```css
.map [title][aria-label][role="button"] {
    margin-top: -5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    &:before {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        display: block;
        content: attr(aria-label);
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 10px;
        line-height: 16px;
        letter-spacing: -1px;
        background: #ffffff;
        border: 2px solid;
        border-radius: 50%;

        color: @red;
        border-color: @red;
    }
}
```